# setting variabels inside functions and use it oustide - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement

I have this code, I want to set the variabel and if function clickButton performed I want the the variable to be set and later used in if().

Can´t get this to work...

```js
var clickButton_1_var = 0;

function clickButton_1() 
{
 clickButton_1_var = 1;

}

if (clickButton_1_var == 1)

{
 document.write("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: inside your if condition you should check for equality, not assign the value, you should use `==` instead: `if (clickButton_1_var == 1)`

Comment: hahahaha now you changed your question using `==` and look! Suddenly it works! :D

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Currently, `Hello World!` won't be output, because you haven't *called* the function. `clickButton_1_var` is always `0`.

Comment: @Shai it's all fine. He just used `=` instead of `==` (later updating the Q)

Answer (score 0):

```
clickButton_1_var = 1;
```

This line will run *when the user clicks a button*, but...

```
if (clickButton_1_var = 1)
```

...this line and its content will only run once, when your program starts. JavaScript does nothing to continually check its status, or re-run a script once something has changed. You're going to want to create a function with that "if" block in it, and run it anytime a function might have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute your function:

```js
var clickButton_1_var = 0;

// define function
var clickButton_1 = function () 
{
 clickButton_1_var = 1;
}

// execute function
clickButton_1();

if (clickButton_1_var == 1)
{
 document.write("Hello World!");
}
```

If you just define, but do not execute, naturally the variable does not change, and will still be 0 when you check it to decide if you want to print or not.